# Chrome Extension: Element null when I execute script in new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

### Problem

I'm trying to create a very simple Chrome extension. It only has 2 files. I have full control of the site, `https://123.123.123.123:3000`.

1. It will create a new tab to `https://123.123.123.123:3000/people/create`
2. It will select an input element by id
3. It will change the value of the input element

Unfortunately, I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null`

No matter what I do, the element is always null.

I've tried the following:

1. Various ways to wait until the page is loaded
2. Enabled CORS for my chrome extension on `https://123.123.123.123:3000`
3. All optional arguments for `chrome.tabs.create`, and `chrome.tabs.executeScript`

---

### Files

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Extension Name",
  "description": "Extension Description",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "browser_action": {},

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "https://123.123.123.123:3000/*"
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({url : 'https://mywebsite.com'}, function (tab) {
    var code = "document.getElementById('first_name').value = 'Bob';";
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: code});
  });
});
```

### Edit #1

My site uses a MEAN stack.

create-person.html

```
<section>
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>{{vm.person._id ? 'Edit Person' : 'New Person'}}</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <form name="vm.form.personForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="vm.save(vm.form.personForm.$valid)" novalidate>
      <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group" show-errors>
          <label class="control-label" for="first_name">First Name</label>
          <input name="first_name" type="text" ng-model="vm.person.first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required>
          <div ng-messages="vm.form.personForm.first_name.$error" role="alert">
            <p class="help-block error-text" ng-message="required">Person full name is required.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">{{vm.person._id ? 'Update' : 'Create'}}</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="vm.error" class="text-danger">
          <strong ng-bind="vm.error"></strong>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the link of your site? Is `first_name` dynamically created?

Comment: @HaibaraAi Oops! I totally forgot to add info about the page itself. I've updated the question to include that info. No, I do not dynamically create `first_name`. I will not be sharing the link (I'm confident that is not the problem).

Comment: @wOxxOm The document IS ready when the script is executed. Anything in a DOMContentLoaded event listener will never execute.

Comment: Oops, I haven't tested it, sorry for misleading you, and thanks for the info. Maybe there's an ID conflict? Try executing that code in the devtools console (F12 key) of that page.

Comment: @wOxxOm The code runs as intended in the console. I tried it on google.com, and my extension works. Something about my site is wigging it out.

Comment: Try adding a `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` listener just before tabs.create to inject the code, then remove the listener.

Comment: chrome.tabs.onUpdated gives the same result. So weird! The document readyState is "complete", but the element is null. I tried this:

`console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("form-control"));`

It works! It returns an HTMLCollection with one item, the input box! However, when I try to act on the collection, like

`document.getElementsByClassName("form-control").first_name`
or
`document.getElementsByClassName("form-control").length`
or
`document.getElementsByClassName("form-control")[0]`

There is nothing, it's empty. It's like it was full one moment, but empty the next.

Comment: Looks like the framework (Angular) recreates the form, deleting the initial DOM. Either wrap your code in `SetTimeout`, or use MutationObserver, or use the framework methods to assign data.

Comment: @wOxxOm You are exactly right! I'm thinking of deleting this question and creating a new one that will be easier to understand.